# How to draw on a photo IMMEDIATELY after taking it, THEN save to storage

Tags: android, canvas, camera, draw, photo

I have searched around and found a few different solutions to this problem but none of them are really what I am looking for.

I am developing an app that lets the user take an image by opening the camera via a MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent as so...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And then saves the image with

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), titleOfPhoto + ".jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
```

I even get the thumbnail back and display it for the user in the onActivityResult() Override.

As the title suggests, what I would like to do is allow the user to draw on the captured image immediately after taking it. But I have no control over what happens between opening the camera and returning to my app with the captured image already saved. Apps like SnapChat and WhatsApp are doing exactly this and so much more, so I know it is possible, but Android does not appear to have this capability built in.

To be clear: The sequence of events needs to be

1) Open the camera

2) Take a picture

3) Draw on the picture

4) Press 'Ok'/'Done' or something

5) Save the edited photo

6) Return thumbnail

Is there anyway to add an event listener to the camera, or open the camera in a different manner that gives more control? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you will have to use the [Camera Framwork API](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html).

The basic of this is to render the camera output on a Surface View in your app. Then when the user takes a picture, capture the state of the surface view. From there you can allow your users to draw on the picture. When they are finished, THEN save the picture and display its thumbnail.

Comment: That Framework API is going to help out a lot, thank you very much! But some of the example code on that article is difficult to convert to my purposes. Could you provide some sample code snippets to help fill in the blanks? For example: How do I manipulate the SurfaceHolder object after the photo is taken? How do I add a drawing feature?

Comment: I don't have code snippets, but off the top of my head I would add a clear canvas view over your SurfaceView and allow the user to draw on that. It would make it appear to be drawing on the picture. I don't know how this will work as far as saving the merged canvas and image, but it might be a start. All of the work I have done for this has been with video, so I unfortunately don't know much about image capture.