# How can I improve/make changes to the orginal Gluon Charm Down Services and use it in my app?

Tags: gradle, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am using Gluon Mobile so that I can use javafx to build applications to iOS and Android. I wonder how I can change/improve on the existing Charm Down library of services that are available: http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/charm-down/

In my case specifically I need to take images that cover the whole screen on mobile. [How can images taking up the whole screen be taken on Android and iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851185/how-can-images-taking-up-the-whole-screen-be-taken-on-android-and-iphone)
And so I am looking to make edits to the `VideoService` and the `PicturesService`. By altering and building onto these existing services I hope to avoid alot of work that has already been done.

How can I edit existing services in Charm Down and use it in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the Charm Down [repository](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/overview) overview, you will find the required instructions for building your own version.

These are the requisites in case you want to fork Gluon Charm Down and build your local version:

- A recent version of JDK 8
- Gradle 2.2 or superior.

To build the Android Services:

- Android SDK: the android SDK must be downloaded. The required Android platform is android-25.
- `ANDROID_HOME` has to be defined as an environment variable, typically by adding it as a gradle property to `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.
- Extras/Android Support Repository and Extras/Google Repository that can be installed with the Android SDK Manager.

To build the iOS Services:

- A Mac with with MacOS X 10.11.5 or superior
- XCode 8.x or superior

Once you have the above requisites, clone the repository from here:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down
```

(You might need to sign in in Bitbucket).

Open the project with your IDE.

[image: Charm Down in NetBeans]

Before modifying any of the services try to build it, install it and use them in your project.

To build the Charm Down services, on the project's root, run on command line:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

[image: Build Charm Down]

If you want to install them, run:

```
./gradlew clean install
```

When the process finishes successfully, the different services are installed in your local `.m2` maven repository.

[image: .m2]

All these required jars can be added to a Gluon Mobile project by including `mavenLocal()` in the list of repositories and the snapshot version ([currently](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/153d43c06ff129f1ff93cc48a030c3a2cf099281/build.gradle?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#build.gradle-19) `3.7.0-SNAPSHOT`, but this could be changed as well):

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.7.0-SNAPSHOT'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'pictures', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
}
```

[image: test project]

Tip: there are too many services that you don't want to modify, so you can comment out some of them from the `settings.gradle` file, mainly to reduce the building time.

Once everything is settled properly, you can start modifying the source code as you need. Anytime you want to check your changes, just run `./gradlew install` and then deploy and run your project.

Comment: I have two unresolved imports inside `PermissionRequestActivity` used in `AndroidPicturesService`, that need: `Android.support.v4.*` I have the sufficent requirements for Android downloaded.

Comment: Check the `gradle.properties` file in the root folder, the key `androidSupportV4Version` has the value `25.1.1`. This means that you need to have `support-v4-25.1.1.aar` in `<Android SDK>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.1.1`. Maybe you have installed any other version (like 25.3.0), so you can set it in the properties file. Reload the project, clean and build again.

Comment: In a standard Gluon project, it say `compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'` inside `build.gradle`. And I have gluon charm inside the `.gradle` folder. Should I replace that `compile` - line to `compile` my copy of Gluon Charm instead? I also wonder if `./gradlew clean build` and `./gradlew clean install` are cmd commands - that should be run with `gradlew.bat` (of the Gluon Charm project) in Windows?

Comment: You are not going to build locally Gluon Charm, so you have to use the online version from the nexus repository. You can run the tasks from your IDE or from a terminal, but you should use the gradle wrapper included in the Charm Down project.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if I complete the `./gradlew clean build, do you mean onto the root project of a GluonTestingProject? Or the to the root of which I have opened the Gluon Charm with, with my chosen IDE Netbeans?

Comment: Charm Down is a library that you build and install locally. Then you can use it in your projects as a regular dependency, with the code I posted in my answer.

Comment: Will I end up with java classes of the PicturesServices and VideoService - that I can test, by running a "GluonTestServicesProject", of which uses the edited services? I have a lack of knowledge when it comes to Gradle, but I want to compile java.

Comment: I opened the downloaded Gluon Charm inside Netbeans, then I right click the project and see the option of "Clean and Build". When I do that it loads for quiet a while - but I recieve around 25 errors, 3 of them related to the VideoService, the rest of them related to InAppBillingService. When it is done, I get a new `3.7.0-SNAPSHOT` jar, of which contain mainifest file `1.0`. As I have now idea what was supposed to happen I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I think we are mixing "Gluon Charm", which is the Gluon Mobile library (commercial), with the "Charm Down" library (open source). The answer above is all about "Charm Down". I'll edit it adding a few screenshots.

Comment: The errors relating to `InAppBillingService` went away when I ran cmd as administrator from the root of the project. The ones with the `VideoService` start with `"illegal character \u2039"`, `activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager‌​.STREAM_MUSIC);`... remains. And continues, "illegal start of expression", "';' expected" regarding the same line of code, AndroidVideoService.java:186

Comment: Weird. Make sure the file is not corrupted, or modify that line, remove the spaces or add a `System.out.println` on top of it, and try again.