# Access device information with gluon

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, gluon-mobile

I was looking for accessing device information like current device WLAN MAC address, IMEI, OS type etc. using Gluon mobile. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Charm Down `Device` [service](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.1/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/DeviceService.html) provides some of the features you are requesting.

- Model: device's model or product
- Uuid: device's universally unique identifier
- Platform: the platform string that the operating system uses to identify itself
- Version: the version number of the device platform
- Serial: the device hardware serial number.
- Wearable: true if the device is a wearable

In your view, you can call the service like:

```
Services.get(DeviceService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
    System.out.printf("Device Model Name: %s", service.getModel());
});
```

Also, you can find implementation details for android [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921b2eac4a3d518cc00ad9108cab89f/plugins/plugin-device/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidDeviceService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and for iOS [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921b2eac4a3d518cc00ad9108cab89f/plugins/plugin-device/ios/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/ios/IOSDeviceService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

If there is any other feature you require, and you want to implement it, you can either clone and modify the service (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998446/how-can-i-improve-make-changes-to-the-orginal-gluon-charm-down-services-and-use) on how to do it), or create a new one (see this [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native)).

Comment: `Services.get(DeviceService.class).ifPresent(service2 -> {
            button.setOnAction(e->{
                System.out.println("Device Model Name: "+ service2.getModel());
                MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("Device Model Name: "+ service2.getModel());
            });
        });`

I tried it to do for several times, but it's not working.

Comment: Are you deploying it to a mobile device?

Comment: Yes, I am installing it in mobile, but also tried to access the device information while running in desktop. It worked nowhere.

Comment: There is no desktop implementation so there it won't work. On android it should. Did you add `device` to `downConfig `?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, adding the device `module` to the `downConfig` helped. :)

Comment: How did you add the `DeviceService` class before? Via dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I added the `dependencies` below `mainClassName` in `build.gradle`  file.